# def anti_vowel - codecademy (python)

Tags: python, string, function

I am a bit stuck on creating the anti_vowel definition:

> Define a function called anti_vowel that takes one string, text, as input and returns the text with all of the vowels removed

This is my attempt:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels=["a","A","e","E","i","I","o","O","u","U"]
    text_input=[""]
    for char in text:
        text_input.append(char)
    av = [char for char in text_input if char not in vowels]
    return av
```

My code returns the input as separate characters.

This is the error I get:

```
Oops, try again. Your function fails on anti_vowel("Hey look Words!"). It returns "['', 'H', 'y', ' ', 'l', 'k', ' ', 'W', 'r', 'd', 's', '!']" when it should return "Hy lk Wrds!".
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
>>> tgt='This is some text with vowels'
>>> vowels='aeiou'
>>> ''.join(e for e in tgt if e.lower() not in vowels)
'Ths s sm txt wth vwls'
```

---

Or, as pointed out in comments, using an actual list comprehension inside join [is better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024):

```
>>> ''.join([e for e in tgt if e.lower() not in vowels])
'Ths s sm txt wth vwls'
```

Comment: [use list comps with str.join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-python/9061024#9061024)

Comment: Well the speed difference there is not *obvious better* but it is *Raymond* so change made ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
return ''.join(av)
```

will make it back into a string from a list.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [str.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) which takes an iterable (like a list) as an argument and returns the string formed by using the object as a separator between each element of that iterable. For example:

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

''.join(lst) # 'abcdefg'
'/'.join(lst) # 'a/b/c/d/e/f/g'
'a'.join(lst # 'aabacadaeafag' etc etc...
```

Note that there are better ways to implement your function. [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)(use THIS [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) in Python2, which iirc is what Codecademy uses for their interpreter, it's changed between versions) is BORN to delete characters from strings.

```
# Python3
def hate_vowels_py3(instring):
    transmap = str.maketrans('', '', 'aeiouAEIOU')
    outstring = instring.translate(transmap)
    return outstring

# Python2
def hate_vowels_py2(instring):
    outstring = instring.translate(None, 'aeiouAEIOU')
    return outstring
```

And using your method, there's even an incremental improvement to be made. Any time you both

- Don't need to keep something in order and
- Don't need to have more than one of something

You should strongly consider using a `set` instead of a `list`. The `set` takes slightly longer to build for the first time, but lookups are MUCH faster. Remember that if you unroll that list comp you have:

```
# example string "Hello world!"

chars_to_delete = ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"]
string = "Hello world!"
output_list = []
char = "H"
can_append_to_list = True
if char == "a": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "e": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "i": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "o": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "u": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "A": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "E": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "I": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "O": can_append_to_list = False
if char == "U": can_append_to_list = False # ten lookups to this list
if can_append_to_list: output_list.append(char)
char = "e"
can_append_to_list = True
# begin again..........
```

As you can see that's a LOT of lookups to that list. Instead use a set, whose lookup time is BLINDINGLY fast. Either use the literal declaration:

```
vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'} # looks like a dict with only keys
# (also IS a dict with no keys, but shhh that's an implementation detail)
```

or you can create one from any iterable by calling `set()` with the iter as an argument

```
vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the list. Using join function you can convert the list to corresponding string.

Try:

```
return ''.join(av)
```

instead of `return av`

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
    textlist = []
    for char in text:
        if char in vowels:
            continue
        else: 
            textlist.append(char)      
    return "".join(textlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

**another simple way to solve this problem...**

```
def anti_vowel (text):
   new_text=""
   for char in text:
     if char not in "aeiouAEIOU":
       new_text+=char
   return new_text
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def anti_vowel(text):
    vowels = "aeiouAEIOU"
    for x in vowels:
        text = text.replace(x, "")
    return text
```

Comment: Please answer the question -- "_Could someone please point me in the right direction to improve my code_" -- rather than posting code that also works.